# TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I keep getting this error: 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined'. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I have 2 of the same loops with different values but they wont execute, the first loop does execute but the rest doesn't. I'm new to jQuery so if someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong, that would be great.

```
for(i=4, x=1; x<16; i=i+3, x=x+3)
{
    var top     = $('.box-' + x).position().top + $('.box-' + x).height() + 10;
    var left    = $('.box-' + x).position().left;

    $('.box-' + i).css({
        top: top,
        left: left
    });
}
```

I keep getting this error: 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined'.

Comment: It means that not all of the `$('.box-' + x)` elements exist on the page.

Comment: It appears there are no elements with class `box-1` (or `box-4`, `box-7`, `box-10` or `box-13`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @dfsq some of the target elements may not be available on the page. So the following code will only operate on those that are:

```
for(i=4, x=1; x<16; i=i+3, x=x+3)
{
    if( $('.box-' + x).length ) {
        var top     = $('.box-' + x).position().top + $('.box-' + x).height() + 10;
        var left    = $('.box-' + x).position().left;

        $('.box-' + i).css({
            top: top,
            left: left
        });
    }
}
```